# Infinite group with the order of abelian subgroup bounded

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

In [Isaac's Finite Group Theory](https://www.ams.org/books/gsm/092/) Page 28, it states：

> There exist infinite groups in which the abelian subgroups have bounded order.

I fail to construct such group. In fact, I'm only able to deduce that the order of every element is bounded by an constant, which makes me feel hard to construct an example.

Hope for an answer!

Comment: Does the group with countable many generators each of which has square the identity work?  I think all the abelian subgroups have two elements (or one). (Comment not an answer since I haven't thought it through.)

Comment: @EthanBolker I think you mean, $$G = \langle x_i \mid x_i^2 = 1, i \in \mathbb N \rangle.$$ I was typing this comment to argue that it works, but I think it doesn't. The cyclic subgroup generated by $x_1 x_2$ is infinite.

Comment: @EthanBolker I wonder how you define the product of each two generators.

Comment: @M.Vinay You're right. What if you declare every square to be the identity (so infinitely many relations)?

Comment: @EthanBolker Such a group is Abelian [$(gh)^2 = 1 \implies gh = (gh)^{-1} = h^{-1}g^{-1} = hg$].

Comment: @WembleyInter Group elements are strings of the generators - multiplication is concatenation. You don't need to consider formal inverses of the generators since every string is the inverse of its reverse.

Comment: @M.Vinay OK back to the drawing board.

Comment: @EthanBolker I just mean what M.Vinay said. If there's no relations between the generators, the product will be of infinite order and if every element has the same (or bounded by the same constant) order, there might be a large abelian group.

Comment: The first thing we can conclude is that this should be an infinite group in which there is some largest element order itself (and in particular every element has finite order), but the group is non-Abelian [this is only a necessary condition]. Edit: No, the Grigorchuk group also doesn't have _bounded_ order for elements. Only finite order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To complement Arturo's answer:

A famous theorem of Ph. Hall is that every infinite locally finite group has an infinite abelian subgroup.

As a consequence, an infinite group whose abelian subgroups are finite of bounded order, has an infinite finitely generated subgroup, clearly sharing the same property. It's, in particular, of finite exponent. So, there's no easy approach to your question.

Adian in 1979 proved that for odd $n\ge 665$ and all $m\ge 2$, the Burnside group $B(m,n)$ (free group of exponent $n$ on $m$ generators) is infinite and all its abelian subgroups are cyclic (hence of order $\le n$).

Note also that finitely generated groups of finite exponent can have infinite abelian subgroups: for instance, if $G$ is infinite, finitely generated of exponent $n$ then $(\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z})\wr G$ is finitely generated of exponent $pn$ and  has an infinite abelian subgroup of exponent $p$.

Answer (score 3):

[Tarski monsters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski_monster_group) provide examples. These are (infinite) groups $G$ in which every proper subgroup $H$ is either trivial, or cyclic of order a fixed prime $p$. In particular, the only abelian subgroups are of order $1$ or $p$.

Such groups exist for every sufficiently large prime, as shown by Olshanski'i. They are 2-generated, nonabelian, simple, and a rich source of all sorts of counterexamples.

Comment: Thanks!  May I ask whether exists an example easier to construct, as Olshanski'i's proof of existence might be a little bit too sophisticated?

Comment: @WembleyInter: I doubt there is anything elementary. After all, that is why Isaacs just *mentions* them and does not even hint at what they look like.